# How to combine two lines of a file into one in python

Tags: python

I have variable,    line:

X

Y

I need to combine X and Y into X, Y so that I can put them in OptionMenu function. How would I do this.

```
w = OptionMenu(root, (#not important), line)
```

gives me two drop down menus with X in one and Y in the other, when I only want one drop down menu with X and Y as options.

Comment: A little more context could be helpful, also more explanation of what form your data is in now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use list

```
line =[X,Y]# a list of all variables

w = OptionMenu(root, (#not important), *line)
```

check out the [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) for more information